# CSS Table-Row Backcolor vs Table Backcolor

Tags: html, css, background-color, css-tables

I have got a problem with CSS.
I table out of div tags.
The problem is:
Behind .table-cell is .table-row, thats why I think, that the background-color for .table-cell is yellow, and next gray.

But when I apply border-top-left-radius to .table-cell, blue comes through the corner, and not gray. [As you can see here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNWyEY) I am using Google Chrome 43.0 on Windows 8.1.

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 - Cell 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 - Cell 2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 - Cell 3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 - Cell 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
   <div class="table-cell">Row 2 - Cell 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 2 - Cell 2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 2 - Cell 3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 2 - Cell 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code look like this:

```
.table {
  display:table;
  background-color:blue;
}

.table-row {
  display:table-row;
  background-color:gray;

}

.table-cell {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I expected the colors in the corners to be gray. But instead they are blue.

Comment: You're right, with mozilla its gray. But with chrome and IE its blue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing your browser cache? I can't reproduce the problem since I get this in Firefox 38 on Mac OSX 10.9.5:
[image: this is my view]

Comment: It's a browser thingy. Using Chrome creates this problem. Not sure about non-hacking solutions though.

Comment: Do you know if theres a hack avaiable?

Answer (score 0):

change background color of `.table`

```
.table {
  display:table;
  background-color:grey;
}
```